# CSS border jagged with different sized/color borders

Tags: css, border, pixel

It seems that when you have an element with different sized/colored borders, you can see a very strange jagged line happening.   I never noticed this before, but was looking at Vimeo's super hot new design when I noticed this (don't really want to say "glitch") weird occurrence.

So if you had a div hanging out, styled as in below, you'll notice a pixel stepping (almost like it's set to inset, rather than solid...)

```
div {
    height            : 25px;
    width             : 50px;
    background        : #eee;
    border-style      : solid;
    border-color      : green;
    border-left-color : black;
    border-width      : 3px 3px 3px 15px;
}
```

Anyone notice this/ know why it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this happens is because it's creating a 'frame' around the box.

Think of a wooden picture frame, you don't use four rectangular pieces of wood to create a frame, you use 4 trapezoidal pieces and put them together.  When you set a larger width on one side, its diagonally rendering it inward towards the corner of the box.

The reason it looks bad is because the antialiasing between borders has never been good.

**Alternative**

You could just do `div:before{border-left: 15px solid #000;}` if you didn't want the borders cropped like that.

Comment: I just always assumed `border-style: inset` used that method, and that border solid would cede the corner to either the horizontal or vertical pixels rather than splitting that space equally. I hadn't realized `border:solid` was built that way. Always so much to learn, haha.

Comment: They both use that kind of style.  I mean, if they did it how you would want to, they'd have to have a separate property for choosing which way you wanted the borders to be split.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a "glitch" - it's how borders work. They connect diagonally.

If you take it one step further and create a `<div>` with no height and width, but a large border you can see the result - http://jsfiddle.net/mFzrA/

BTW - this is the technique being used to create pure CSS triangles and speech bubbles. You just make 3 of the borders transparent and the 4th gives you a nice triangle.

Comment: Totally.  I've messed around with making shapes with borders, though I hadn't really understood why it worked. Now i feel a bit sheepish...

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to suggest using box-shadow on the border with bigger border-width to avoid "jagged line".
Works for me, hope it helps :)

```
div {
    height            : 25px;
    width             : 50px;
    background        : #eee;
    border-style      : solid;
    border-color      : green;
    border-width      : 3px 3px 3px 0px;
    box-shadow:-15px 0px black;
}
```